# Keytool gives different certificates for different passwords for an Android app

Tags: android, keytool

Given the command-

`keytool -list -keystore "path\debug.keystore"`

when entering 'android' as password, I can see one certificate.

But when using-

`keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "path\debug.keystore" | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base65`

What happens is that different password given to the keytool ('android' among them) results in different output.
But given no password (just clicking enter) the output is the same as when entering 'android' as password, plus a warning message about the integrity. (which was not printed when entering any arbitrary passwords)

So, I figured out this means only one certificate in the keystore, but the output is different for different passwords? what is that?

Comment: I guess you are hashing an error message.

Comment: You are right, thank you. I have waist days trying figure it out.